# When opening my laptop, it's like command-tab was pressed

Tags: macos

Every time I open my laptop, it acts as though command-tab was pressed. I have a new MacBook Air OSX v10.8.4. I noticed this with my previous MacBook Air as well. I'd like to open my laptop and have the last app I was using in focus, instead of the penultimate.

Comment: have you ever tried to create a new administrative account? if not, do so and se if there is a change!

Comment: The culprit is the penultimate setting.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Macmaniman. I'm not a big fan of having to create a new account just to make this work right. I think I'll bring it into the genius bar and see what they say. The reason I buy Apple is to get stuff that just works.

Comment: @Buscar웃, not sure what you mean?

Comment: disable Penultimate and then also disable the wifi to test. Now close and open the lid.

Comment: Hmm... When I typed "penultimate", I meant "second". I don't think I have an app called Penultimate.

Comment: Q-instead of the penultimate-EQ- it is part of Evernote ? or are we on different planets!

Comment: Who talks like this anyway .) merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penultimate‎
next to the last <the penultimate chapter of a book>. 2. : of or relating to the next to the last syllable of a word <a penultimate accent>. — pen·ul·ti·mate·ly adverb.

Comment: i understand what you say, but they will do the same, what i mean to do is to find the problem, this is not the solution, you can still keep your old account!however if you make a new account and the problem does not occur we can rule out, hardware and os software, so if you are open to it lets try that out first and save you a trip to a genius bar!